# Reverse SSH in Git Bash fails with `connect_to localhost port X: failed`

Tags: windows, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to help my coworkers create a reverse SSH tunnel from their local PC to our remote development server.

The reverse SSH tunnel works perfectly for me. It's not working for them.

The command they're running looks like this:

```bash
ssh -v -R 9000:localhost:9000 user@example.dev
```

Here's an example of the output they get

```
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype forwarded-tcpip rchan 3 win 2097152 max 32768
debug1: client_request_forwarded_tcpip: listen localhost port 9000, originator ::1 port 36142
debug1: getsockopt TCP_NODELAY: Invalid argument                                              
debug1: connect_next: host localhost ([::1]:9000) in progress, fd=8
debug1: channel 1: new [::1]                                                                  
debug1: confirm forwarded-tcpip                                                               
debug1: channel 1: connection failed: Connection refused
debug1: getsockopt TCP_NODELAY: Invalid argument                                              
debug1: connect_next: connect host localhost ([::1]:9000) in progress, fd=9                  
connect_to localhost port 9000: failed
debug1: channel 1: free: ::1, nchannels 2
```

Vs the output I get

```
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype forwarded-tcpip rchan 3 win 2097152 max 32768
debug1: client_request_forwarded_tcpip: listen localhost port 9001, originator ::1 port 59996
debug1: connect_next: start for host localhost ([::1]:9001)                                  
debug1: getsockopt TCP_NODELAY: Invalid argument                                              
debug1: connect_next: connect host localhost ([::1]:9001) in progress, fd=8                  
debug1: channel 1: new [::1]                                                                  
debug1: confirm forwarded-tcpip                                                               
debug1: channel 1: connection failed: Connection refused
debug1: connect_next: start for host localhost ([127.0.0.1]:9001)                
debug1: connect_next: connect host localhost ([127.0.0.1]:9001) in progress, fd=9
debug1: channel 1: connected to localhost port 9001                              
debug1: channel 1: free: ::1, nchannels 2
```

The main difference I see is that in my output, the IP changes to v4 whereas in theirs the IP stays V6. The port numbers are intentionally different (they use 9000, I use 9001)

We tried turning Windows Defender completely off in case there was a firewall problem. No dice.

---

We're running the command in Git Bash. `which bash` returns `/usr/bin/bash`. If it makes any difference, I'm trying to set my coworker up with Xdebug on a remote server.

Comment: Have you tried with `ssh -4 ...`?

Comment: Good idea @nickie. Unfortunately they get the same result as before.

Comment: How about `ssh -v -R 9000:127.0.0.1:9000 user@example.dev`, instead of `localhost`?

Comment: Another good suggestion that I've seen work elsewhere but sadly that didn't work either @nickie. Thanks tho

Comment: The problem ended up having to do with an unmanaged switch my coworkers were plugged into. When they plugged their computer directly into the wall instead of the unmanaged switch between their PCs and the wall, they were able to connect. I'll post back with an anwser when I know _why_ that caused a problem.